# How to remove the dark shadow of the screen when a Dialog is shown?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-dialog

When a `Dialog` is shown then the background of screen is darkened. I want to remove this darkness so that the screen looks like normal. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the tint color of the parent form, you can also set this in the look and feel class and within the theme constants in the resource editor.

Answer (score 1):

When you show a `Dialog` the background becomes a `Form`, changing its style you can modify the background of a `Dialog`. I don´t really know if you can make this `Form` transparent. I use the LWUIT-Theme creator and modifiying the `Form`´s style, I can change the background for an image o for one colour.

Try it here! 
http://lwuit.java.net/

Comment: It's not the background of the Dialog which I am talking about ! It's the background color of the Form which is hidden by the Dialog ! Anyway I found the solution : I set the Form's `tintColor` before showing the Dialog.

Comment: I know that is not the background of the `Dialog`. The background showed under the `Dialog` have the `Form` style. If you had used the resource editor you would have seen it.

Answer (score 0):

just add below code on your dialog:
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);